# Access API hosted in Azure VM on Private IP via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, networking, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I have Apache server running on Azure VM that exposes certain APIs. I am triggering those APIs using web activity of Azure Data Factory. My question is How can I acess the API over private network rather than using public API. that way I can insulate my VM from outside access and hence making it secure

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) to transfer between a cloud data stores and a data store in private network.

If you want to perform data integration securely in a private network environment, which does not have a direct line-of-sight from the public cloud environment, you can install a self-hosted IR on premises environment behind your corporate firewall, or inside a virtual private network. The self-hosted integration runtime only makes outbound HTTP-based connections to open internet.

Note:Self-Hosted IR only supports Windows OS System so far. More detailed steps,please refer to this [document](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime--part-1/).

Comment: I am not looking for accessing via my private org network. I am looking for accessing API hosted on Azure VM itself. In AWS Cloud it so much easier if components belongs to same VPC they can talk to each other on private network